# How can I group my daily date column into monthly date with R?

Tags: r, date, converters

I have a dataframe called police_notifications and this is what it looks like.

```
datum
1 06-03-2019 11:34:57
2 06-03-2019 11:15:12
3 06-03-2019 11:23:22
4 06-03-2019 11:23:22
5 06-03-2019 11:15:12
6 06-03-2019 11:07:07
7 06-04-2019 11:05:20
8 06-04-2019 11:10:30
```

And the date column goes on from 12-11-2015 until 06-03-2019. The column date exists out of daily dates.
Each row from the date column represents 1 value. So what I basically want is an extra column added with the total value from 1 month, so I want it like this:

```
value    date
100    01-03-2019
200    01-04-2019
150    01-05-2019
```

I was looking for a simple solution to convert my daily date, to month with the total value added next to it.

Extra information:

```
                 datum                                   locatie
1  06-03-2019 11:34:57                                   De Bilt
2  06-03-2019 11:23:22                                     Breda
3  06-03-2019 11:23:22                                     Breda
4  06-03-2019 11:15:12                                  Nijmegen
5  06-03-2019 11:07:07                                  Deventer
6  06-03-2019 11:05:27                                   Tilburg
7  06-03-2019 11:04:37 A15 hectometerpaal 144 (thv Neder-Betuwe)
8  06-03-2019 10:59:33                            Oud-Beijerland
9  06-03-2019 10:52:44                                  Den Haag
10 06-03-2019 10:26:46                                  Den Haag
```

Comment: Can you add column names, not sure if integers 1 to 8 are row numbers of dataframe column values. Can you share reproducible example using head(dput(dataframe_name), 10)

Comment: Added some more information using your code

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the timestamp into a string which contains the first day of the month, and then apply a group_by() and count to find the number of notifications in a given month (if you want to add the number as a new column use the group_by and mutate version):

```
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:8,
                 timestamp = c("06-03-2019 11:34:57", "06-03-2019 11:15:12", "06-03-2019 11:23:22",
                               "06-03-2019 11:23:22", "06-03-2019 11:15:12", "06-03-2019 11:07:07",
                               "06-04-2019 11:05:20", "06-04-2019 11:10:30"),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(month = format(as.POSIXct(timestamp, format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), "01-%m-%Y")) %>% 
  group_by(month) %>% 
  count()

df %>% 
  mutate(month = format(as.POSIXct(timestamp, format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), "01-%m-%Y")) %>% 
  group_by(month) %>% 
  mutate(n = n())
```